# how to use the word occur?

Tags: prepositions, vocabulary, verbs, synonyms

I am wondering if which of the following could be correct?

A. Mathematics occurred to develop all sciences.

B. Mathematics arouse  to develop all sciences.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you mean to say *arose,* not *arouse.* Arouse/arousing/aroused usually refers to the act of exciting someone sexually.

"Occurred" isn't the proper word here. To occur is to happen, like an event, and it can imply that whatever is occurring did so out of its own agency, since "occur" is not a transitive verb -- things do not "occur" other things.

In other words, things that occur do so on their own, at least in the context of the given sentence. An earthquake or forest fire can occur, but Germany did not "occur" the invasion of Poland in 1939. "The invasion of Poland occurred in 1939" would be proper, however.

Mathematics did not occur because mathematics is not an event, it is a field of study. "Mathematics arose to develop all sciences" would be an acceptable use of the verb, since mathematics was developed over a period of time; it didn't just pop into existence. Not only that, but it didn't happen on its own. Many scholars and mathematicians developed the field over the course of history.

Comment: But saying that “it arose to develop” implies that it was invented for that purpose.  I’d rather say that the development of mathematics help further all sciences.

Comment: That is true, although the operative phrase there is "to develop;" I was just saying I think that the verb "arose" fits, without much mind to the rest of the sentence.